# If two ROW's match, return a specific value in next column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ltdw.png)

Hi all,

I have a big data set, If a Row match with next Row then get a 1 in next column; Here I attached one picture for your reference. In this case company Berkshire Hathaway Inc. is matching with next row and only two row items for this company.

Thanks in advance …

Answer (score 0):

Try this in D2,

```
=if(countifs(a$2:a2, a2, b$2:b2, b2, c$2:c2, c2)=1, 1, "")
```